# Fail to extract the last hidden layer from DistilBERT

Tags: tensorflow, bert-language-model, fine-tuning, distilbert

I want to extract the last hidden layer from the DistilBERT for sentiment analysis from huggingface IMDb dataset.
I've tried several ways (at least I know...) to get the last hidden layer state; however, I always encounter the following error, please help me, thanks first!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzg4o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKlwa.jpg)